# Communicate between Worklight app and "cloud" MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, worklight-adapters

I want to access online databases from my Worklight app. 
But I have many questions around it.
- Can I create an online MySQL database? and How? When I add SQLAdapter, and test my app, it work with "localhost". But I want to store my database online and use my app to read/write data from this database.
Thank all for helping me :D
P/s: sorry for my terrible english.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use mysql on cloud? Which cloud provider are you targeting. The configuration steps depends on the cloud provider you choose. Please refer to the provider's documentation.
Regarding your question of connecting to cloud based mysql db from sql adapter, try with replacing the localhost with the ipaddress and username, password with the credentials to be used for accessing your cloud based db.JDBC should be supported for accessing most cloud db's ,so driverClass in the dataSourceDefinition need not be changed.